# Filling in defaults when concatenating dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am concatenating two dataframes along the column axis as follows:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

The two dataframes' indexes are not the same, however, so in `df` the missing values are filled with NaN's. This was perfectly fine with me until I added some boolean columns to `df1` and `df2`. Now, just as before, the missing values are filled with `NaN`'s but since the bool type has no `NaN` values the dtype of the boolean columns in `df` is `object`. This causes an error in expressions like `df[~df['some_bool_col']]`.

What is the easiest way to fill missing values with `False` when concatenating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), values to `bool`s are converted [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706126/filling-in-defaults-when-concatenating-dataframes/44706239#comment76395312_44706239):

```
df['bool_col'] = df['bool_col'].fillna(False)
```

And for multiple columns:

```
cols = ['bol1_col','bool2_col']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(False)
```

Comment: turns out astype is not necessary - it is automatically converted